# NoMethod - Undefined method <method name> error even if the method has been defined

Tags: ruby

I'm getting a no method - method undefined error while I am defining a method AFTER a particular method ends. The method defined before this one has an if..else statement block which might be creating an issue here

I've tried defining the mentioned method before the "problem making method" and in that case, my method works properly. But if any method is defined after that particular method, I get the same error message.

```rb
def display_board(board)
puts " #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} "
puts "-----------"
puts " #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} "
puts "-----------"
puts " #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} "
end
def input_to_index(pos)
  pos = pos.to_i - 1
end

def valid_move?(board, pos)
  if pos.between?(0,8)
    if board[pos] == " "
      return true
    else
      return false
  end
  else
    return false
end
def move(board, pos, type)
  board[pos] = "#{type}"  
end
end
```

It should ideally pass all the test cases. But I'm getting this particular error:

```
1) ./lib/turn.rb #move allows "X" player in the bottom right and "O" in the top left
     Failure/Error: move(board, 0, "O")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `move' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LibTurnRb::Move:0x0000000001db90d8>
     # ./spec/turn_spec.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly, issues like this are much easier to understand.

Comment: @TomLord I'm agree!

Comment: I agree too, apologies and thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close your `valid_move?` method before declare a new method (`move`)...

```
def valid_move?(board, pos)
  if pos.between?(0,8)
    if board[pos] == " "
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  else
    return false
  end
end

def move(board, pos, type)
  board[pos] = "#{type}"  
end
```

If you declare `move` method inside another method, is not visible in the main program.

Answer (score 0):

your `move` defined in `valide_move?` maybe try a better code editor prettifying. :)

```rb
def valid_move?(board, pos)
  if pos.between?(0,8)
    if board[pos] == " "
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  else
    return false
  end

  def move()
        board[pos] = "#{type}"
        puts "a" 
  end
end
```